# The middle row of matrix and cases does not align at baseline

Tags: matrices, arrays, cases

When I wrote a row vector in a `matrix` or a 3-branch function in a `cases`, I noticed that the middle row does not align at the baseline of the content outside. As one must be conformed to university thesis rules (unfortunately), the result of such misalignment looks quite jarring.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}
\newcommand\test{%
  A\rule{5pt}{0.02pt}%
  \begin{matrix}
  \,\color{blue}\rule{5pt}{0.02pt}A
  \end{matrix},\quad
  \begin{cases}
   & \color{blue}A\rule{5pt}{0.02pt}
  \end{cases}%
  \rule{5pt}{0.02pt}A%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\test
\]
\linespread{1.6}\selectfont
\[
\test
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: misaligned]

When being viewed at 6400%, the top-left reveals itself to be misaligned as well.

I suspected this to be an issue with how strut was implemented.

Comment: Use `array` instead of `cases` and use a 3-row array also for the black `A_` outside with the first and the third rows empty `{}`. I guess the root of the problem is changing the `linespread`.

Comment: @AboAmmar `array` should produce the same result as `matrix`. Without `\linespread`, these two “almost” align as desired. Try `10pt` and `12pt` class options and also try removing the `\,` to see that they do not actually align (offset by a tiny amount). `cases` uses `1.2` as `\arraystretch`, so yes, it seems that stretching the line spoils everything. But keep in mind that without stretching the problem is still there (just barely visible)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: you can set `baseline` option in the optional arguments of `+matrix`, `+pmatrix`, and `+cases` environments:

(Some code is taken from Pantigny's answer).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\leavevmode
\rlap{{\color{blue}\rule{6cm}{0.02pt}}}
$A = \begin{+pmatrix}[baseline=2]
\sqrt{2} & 1 & 1 \\
A & A & A \\
2 & 2 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{+pmatrix}
= \begin{+cases}[baseline=2]
\sqrt{2} & 1 & 1 \\
A & A & A \\
2 & 2 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{+cases}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the matrices, you can use `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and its key `baseline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode
\rlap{{\color{blue}\rule{5cm}{0.02pt}}}
$A = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[baseline=2]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2}} & p & 1-p \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & p & 1+p
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]